# How to convert Esri ASCII (.asc) to use on a leaflet map?

Tags: node.js, geolocation, leaflet, gdal, esri

As part of my software I have to somehow convert and display Esri ASCII (.asc) files on a leaflet map.
The files are in the filesystem and the backend is in nodeJS.

.asc is a raster format and gdal_translate manages to translate the files as I like. Unfortunately I can't use GDAL in node and as far, as I see it, gdal-node is not able to convert the files. Manually converting files is not an option.

My data is always somehow geo referenced, so if I get an image, it has to be placed on the right spot on the worldmap.

Help would be highly appreciated, because I feel kinda overwhelmed by all this GEO stuff.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the normal set of features Leaflet offers, like zooming, what you need is called a map tile service.

There are a few map tile standards that Leaflet supports.  Generally though, making map tiles is complicated — particularly if your ASCII grids are in lat/long but you're using a background layer from Google, Bing, OSM that's in "web Mercator" — so you probably don't want to write one in Node yourself.

Look at [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/) and see if that will fit into your setup.